# How to bind a function to change of URL query string, NOT to hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

As the title suggests, I'm looking to bind a function to the change of the URL query string.

**An example:**

**from:** `/baby`

**to:** `/baby/?_bc_fsnf=1&brand[]=37`

To elaborate, I'd want the function to run when the **from** turns into the **to**.

Cheers!

Comment: A URL change like that is going to refresh the page. There's no binding to that event, unless you monitor onbeforeunload, but that's not going to tell you what URL you're going to, just the one you're on.

Comment: You have to perform the check every time the page loads and detect whether your query string is not empty.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm consoling on doc ready and it's simply not refreshing the whole page. I'm preserving the log and consoling time--never changes.

Comment: I would suggest [edit]ing your question to include what you've tried.

Answer (score 9):

If your page is not refreshing, someone is probably calling `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState` to change the URL.

There is built-in way to track when `pushState` and `replaceState` are called, but you can track them yourself by wrapping each function using this `track` utility:

```js
function track (fn, handler, before) {
  return function interceptor () {
    if (before) {
      handler.apply(this, arguments)
      return fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } else {
      var result = fn.apply(this, arguments)
      handler.apply(this, arguments)
      return result
    }
  }
}

var oldQs = location.search

function handler () {
  console.log('Query-string changed:',
    oldQs || '(empty)', '=>',
    location.search || '(empty)'
  )

  oldQs = location.search
}


// Assign listeners
history.pushState = track(history.pushState, handler)
history.replaceState = track(history.replaceState, handler)
window.addEventListener('popstate', handler)


// Example code to change the URL
history.pushState(null, 'Title 1', '/baby/?key=value')
history.replaceState(null, 'Title 2', '/baby/?_bc_fsnf=1&brand[]=37')
```